# Number of IID bernoulli random variables required for the majority to output 1 with high probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Problem:**

An algorithm A solves a problem (where the answer is either yes or no) correctly with probability $p = 0.51$. Another algorithm B will call algorithm A a constant $n$ number of times, and then output the what the majority of the answers were (e.g. if it calls A 3 times, and A outputs yes twice and no once, then B will output yes). We need to find an $n$ such that B outputs the correct answer with probability $\geq 1-2^{-20}$.

**My attempt:**

I believe we are looking at a set of IID Bernoulli random variables, and I think I am supposed to use Chernoff Bounds to find and prove an $n$ that satisfies the constraints, but I am not sure how exactly to do that.

Comment: Most algorithms run on the same data again and again will often give the same answer whether or not that is correct.  Assuming independence seems a very strong and dubious assumption.

Comment: I believe the original problem is intended to be a probability problem more so than an algorithms one, and we are to assume that Algorithm A is always going to output the correct answer with probability p each time it is called.

Comment: @Insanit I think the inequality $p\cdot P(X>n/2)+(1-p)\cdot P(X<n/2)\geq 1-2^{20}$, where $X\sim Bin(n,p)$ with $p=0.51$. But this works only if n is even.

Comment: $1-2^{20}$ does not seem a very reasonable value for a probability. It's quite a lot less then zero...

Comment: @ECL yes you are right, typo on my part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $X_i$ are the indicator random variables for the success of the $i$th trial of A, then B's success is given by the indicator of the event $S_n > \frac{n}{2}$ where $S_n := \sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. By the law of large numbers, as $n \to \infty$ we have $\frac{1}{n}S_n \to 0.51$ in probability, so
$P(S_n > n/2) = P(S_n/n > 1/2) \to 1$, or equivalently $P(S_n \le n/2) \to 0$. Concentration inequalities can help quantify how quickly this convergence happens by providing bounds on this probability $P(S_n \le n/2)$ in terms of $n$.

---

Approach with [Chernoff bound (multiplicative form)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound#Multiplicative_form_(relative_error)):

$$P(S_n \le n/2) = P(S_n \le (1 - 51^{-1})0.51n) \le \left(\frac{e^{1/51}}{(52/51)^{52/51}}\right)^{0.51 n}.$$
Setting the right-hand side equal to $2^{-20}$ yields $n \ge \left\lceil\frac{1}{0.51(\frac{52}{51} \log \frac{52}{51} - \frac{1}{51})} \cdot 20 \log(2) \right\rceil = 142,324$

---

Approach with [Hoeffding's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hoeffding%27s_inequality):

$$P(S_n \le n/2)
= P(S_n - 0.51 n \le -0.01n)
\le \exp\left(-\frac{2(0.01 n)^2}{n}\right) = e^{-0.0001n}.$$
Setting the right-hand side equal to $2^{-20}$ yields $n \ge \lceil 10^4 \cdot 20 \log(2)\rceil =  138,630$.

---

Rough approach using Central Limit Theorem:

For large $n$, the sum $S_n$ is approximately normal with mean $0.51 n$ and variance $(0.51)(0.49) n = 0.2499 n$.

$$P(S_n \le n/2) = P\left(\frac{S_n - 0.51 n}{\sqrt{0.2499 n}} \le -\frac{0.01 n}{\sqrt{0.2499 n}}\right)
\approx \Phi\left(-\frac{0.01 n}{\sqrt{0.2499 n}}\right)
= \Phi\left(-\frac{0.01 }{\sqrt{0.2499}}\sqrt{n}\right).$$

Using a computer or a normal table, you can check $\Phi^{-1}(2^{-20}) \approx  -4.763$ (e.g., `qnorm(2^(-20))` in R), so $n \ge \lceil 4.763^2 \cdot 0.2499 / 0.01^2\rceil = 56,693$.

---

Computationally: it seems the Central Limit Theorem approximation works well. Running `qbinom(2^(-20), 56693, 0.51) / 56693` yields `0.4999912` which shows $P(S_n \le 0.4999912 \cdot n) \approx 2^{-20}$ for $n = 56693$. Perhaps the Chernoff and Hoeffding bounds applied above are a bit conservative.

Comment: Thanks, for the Chernoff bound approach, what does the delta represent and why is it 1/51 here?

Comment: @Insanit I set $(1-\delta)\mu$ equal to $0.5 n$ with $\mu=0.51 n$ and solved for $\delta$.